# PHP + MySQL: Edit page not displaying all data from db

Tags: php, mysql, database

I code an edit page for my blog, but not all data from database are displayed. Just 3 / 7 = title, point, publish. Option, seo, perex and content are not. Pic is irrelevant because there is no option to upload yet.  Here is my code:

```
    if(is_post_request()) {
    $page = [];
    $page['id'] = $id;
    $page['title'] = $_POST['title'] ?? '';  
$page['pic'] = $_POST['pic'] ?? '';
    $page['perex'] = $_POST['perex'] ?? '';          
    $page['option'] = $_POST['option'] ?? '';
    $page['seo'] = $_POST['seo'] ?? '';
    $page['pointa'] = $_POST['pointa'] ?? '';
    $page['content'] = $_POST['content'] ?? '';
    $page['publish'] = $_POST['publish'] ?? '';
    
    $result = update_page($page);
    if($result === true) {
        redirect_to(url_for('/blog/public/clanoktemplate.php?id=' . $id));
    } else {
    $errors = $result;
    }
} else {
    $page = find_page_by_id($id);
} 
    
    <form action="<?php echo url_for('/blog/private/edit.php?id=' . h(u($id))); ?>" method="POST">
            <h2>Tu môžeš upraviť článok</h2>
                <div class="part">
                    <label for="title">Názov článku:</label><br>
                    <input type="text" id="title" name="title" value="<?php echo h($page['title']); ?>" required><br>
                </div>
                <div class="part">
                    <label for="option">Kategória:</label>
                    <select type="option" id="option" name="option" value="<?php echo h($page['option']); ?>" required>
                            <option value="pristup">Prístup</option>
                            <option value="sebaedukacia" selected>Sebaedukácia</option>
                            <option value="sebarodicovstvo">Sebarodičovstvo</option>
                            <option value="zasadneschopnosti">Zásadné schopnosti</option>
                            <option value="dusevnymajetok">Duševný majetok</option>
                            <option value="vzdelaniebuducnosti">Vzdelanie budúcnosti</option>
                        </select><br>
                </div>
                <div class="part">
                    <label for="seo" id="seo" name="seo">SEO:</label><br>
                    <input type="text" id="seo" name="seo" value="<?php echo h($page['seo']); ?>"><br>
                </div>
                <div class="part">
                    <label for="pointa" id="pointa" name="pointa">Hlavná myšlienka:</label><br>
                    <input type="text" id="pointa" name="pointa" value="<?php echo h($page['pointa']); ?>"><br>
                </div>
                <div class="part">
                    <label for="perex" id="perex" name="perex">Perex:</label><br>
                    <textarea id="perex" name="perex" rows="4" value="<?php echo h($page['perex']); ?>" required></textarea><br>
                </div>
                <button type="button" id="pic" name="pic"> Nahrať obrázok </button><br>
                <div class="part">
                    <label for="content" id="content" name="content">Celý článok:</label><br>
                    <textarea id="content" name="content" rows="20" value="<?php echo h($page['content']); ?>"required></textarea><br>
                </div>
                <div class="mini-part" style="padding-bottom: 15px; font-size: 20px; text-align: left; ">
                    <label for="visible" id="publish" name="publish">Viditeľný:</label>
                    <input type="hidden" id="publish" name="publish" value="0">
                        <input type="checkbox" id="publish" name="publish" value="1"<?php if($page['publish'] == "1") { echo " checked"; } ?>><br>
                </div>
```

Why is that? How can I fix it? Thank you for your help.

Par ex. output of var_dump($page); =>
array(10) { **["id"]**=> string(3) "148" **["title"]**=> string(7) "Testing" **["seo"]**=> string(9) "seo words" **["pic"]**=> string(0) "" **["perex"]**=> string(38) "Testing is needed before going online." **["content"]**=> string(637) "The whole comes here. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Everything except this editing page work just fine. " ["datum"]=> string(19) "2022-04-08 20:59:15" ["pointa"]=> string(25) "the main point comes here" ["kateg"]=> string(17) "zasadneschopnosti" ["publish"]=> string(1) "1" }

It looks perfectly fine.

Comment: what is `find_page_by_id` doing? I'd bet it's only returning `title`, `point`, and `publish`. And what is `h()` doing when echoing `$page['seo']`?

Comment: h() stands for for  htmlspecialchars(). So you can ignore that part. Find_page_by_id should return all of tha data.                                           function find_page_by_id($id) {
  global $db;

  $sql = "SELECT * FROM article WHERE id='" . db_escape($db, $id) . "'";
  $result = mysqli_query($db, $sql);
  confirm_result_set($result);
  $page = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
  mysqli_free_result($result);
  return $page; }

Comment: what outputs when you do `var_dump($page); die();` after `$page = find_page_by_id($id);`? Can you prove to use that `article` has those columns?

Comment: It correctly displays all of the data. The ones that are not displayed in my form, too.

Comment: Are you sure that `$page` is an array and has all of those keys? Per the example I put together at https://3v4l.org/rE9pr it works just fine _as long as `$page` is an associative array with the expected keys_. Are you inspecting the HTML to confirm if the inputs' `value` parameter is empty, or are you just viewing the rendered page? Please edit your question to include an example of a full var_dump of the `$pages` variable.

Comment: I make some changes acording gview, and now it is working except perex. But that means (when var_dump() is ok) that the HTML part is disfunctional.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using [textarea incorrectly](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/textarea).  Textareas do not use a value= attribute.

Should be

```
 <textarea> ...value of data here </textarea>
```

Fix your code like so:

```
 <textarea id="perex" name="perex" rows="4" required><?php echo h($page['perex']); ?></textarea><br>
```

You have [a similar issue with option](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/select). Again the select tag does not have a value attribute.  Each individual option has a value attribute and when the form is submitted, the value will be set to the value of the option that was selected.

For display of the option you need to write code that matches the value you are setting in your database to the value of the option, and for the option that matches the prior value, you need to add "selected".

Typically this is done with a ternary, so for each option you need something like this:

```
  <option value="pristup" <?php h($page['option']) === 'pristup' ? ' selected' : '' ?>>Prístup</option>
```

Comment: Thank you gview, now the parts of perex and content are working. Just option left.

Comment: I updated the answer to explain your mistake with option.  In general, you have to understand how html form elements work in order to make them work with php.

Comment: Yes, it is similar also to $page['publish'].  I thought it would be using foreach or something like that (not individually). Thank you for your help.